# Rhythmic grinding noise most audible when idle

Tags: noise, vauxhall, astra

Hi not sure if this is the right place to ask.

I have a 2011 EU Vauxhall Astra, with about 120k miles, that’s making a strange rhythmic grinding sound.  The timing belt was recently replaced as it was worn but the noise didn’t go away.

I think it speeds up and occurs more frequently at higher RPM although it’s hard to be completely sure as regular engine noise drowns it out.

It sounds slightly metallic and I can feel the car slightly vibrate with each cycle.

I’ve looked all over google for an answer and I haven’t found much.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Thanks

[Video of engine noise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPHla.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! That sounds more like the catapillar drive from the Typhoon in *The Hunt for Red October*! (J/K) ... that is a strange noise. Rhythmic as you stated and not directly associated with the engine (or so it would seem). Does it change any when you put it in drive or reverse (assuming an automatic transmission)?

Comment: No change at all when the car is put in reverse or drive.  Not sure what to think lol

Comment: We had a similar question here, long ago. In the end one took the time to do a timing analysis of the video and was able to elaborate the diameter of the faulty pulley

Comment: And that was it: https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/38580/strange-noise-from-timing-belt-area